# How do I create hard-stop backgrounds in SASS/SCSS?

Tags: css, sass, linear-gradients

I've created a gradient that has 11 hard stops, creating the illusion of 11 separate boxes.

[image]

As it stands now, there's a % of the width hard-coded into the linear gradient. I can't help but think there's a much more efficient way (via SCSS?) rather than coding this out as such:

```css
.color-bar {
      background: linear-gradient( to left,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 9.09%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 9.09%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 18.18%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 18.18%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 27.27%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) 27.27%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) 36.36%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) 36.36%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) 45.45%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 45.45%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 54.54%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, .6) 54.54%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, .6) 63.63%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) 63.63%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) 72.72%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 72.72%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 81.81%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, .9) 81.81%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 90.09%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
      height: 50px;
      width: 550px;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-bar"></div>
```

[Here's a rough Codepen in action.](http://codepen.io/jwindeknecht/pen/OpqrQg)

Thanks for any input you can provide.

Comment: I mean, if you got the desired result I don't see what the issue is really. It's not pretty - sure, but who cares? This is perfectly valid code.

Comment: @Chris I guess If OP is asking for a SCSS method is to create a function that you can reuse, maybe where you can just change a number to set the number of the steps on the gradient instead of make your own calculations each time

Comment: @DaniP, yeah that would make sense from a reusability standpoint, if that's the question. If not however, I personally don't see the point of changing anything as you still get css in the end anyway.

Comment: By the way OP, your second box from the left seems to have a gradient itself - not a fixed color like the other boxes.

Comment: @DaniP Yeah, I'm just thinking down the road if I wanted to reuse this. If I wanted to have 4 stops, or 20 to keep myself from coding each of those percentages out.

Comment: @Chris See above. And you're right! I forgot a step, good catch.

Comment: Your question is tagged [performance] but your question seems to imply you're looking at efficiency in terms of productivity, not performance. Which one is it?

Comment: @BoltClock I'm pretty sure he meant productivity. Is there such a tag? And I wonder who would deserve a gold badge in it, since answering SO questions is pretty much counter-productive. :)

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu: I don't know if Code Review takes questions like this. Maybe it does.

Comment: @BoltClock [You could always ask](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) ;-)

Comment: @BoltClock Are you implying you consider this question off-topic on SO - CSS? Because it's  where I'd expect to find a `sass` function to create custom hard-stop backgrounds from arguments. (Leaving the fact I just answered it aside).

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu: The question asks how to optimize working code - that's Code Review territory. But you have a point - if the question is about how to write SCSS that generates a given piece of CSS...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me a bit of fiddling, but here it is:

```css
@function hard-stops($direction, $from, $to, $steps) {
  $output: unquote("linear-gradient(") + $direction;
  @for $i from 0 through $steps {
    $output: $output + ', ' 
                     + mix($from, $to, $i*100/$steps) + ' ' 
                     + percentage($i/($steps+1)) + ', '
                     + mix($from, $to, $i*100/$steps) + ' ' 
                     + percentage(($i+1)/($steps+1));
  }
  $output: $output + ')';

  @return $output;
}
.color-bar {
  height: 50px;
  width: 550px;
  background: hard-stops(to left, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0), 10);
}
```

[`jsFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/hyyszwvx/).

The limitation is: one needs to pass mix-able colors (`black`, for example, is not, no idea why - I'm not much of an expert in `sass`).

Comment: Wow, very cool way of approaching it. I hadn't considered color-mixing. [Here is my rough attempt](http://codepen.io/jwindeknecht/pen/XMGwNb) that uses other colors.

Comment: @JoeW, Well, it didn't make sense not to, even if your example only uses 1 color. In the end, color mixing is one of the major reasons people use `sass`. That and perhaps nesting selectors and `@media` queries. Congrats on your first question, btw, It's rare that people start off with such a good/well-received question. Welcome to [so] & happy coding! :: }<(((*> ::)